# Is there any other way than Metadata API how custom application to custom tabs assignment can be retrieved?

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api, metadata

Is there any other way than Metadata API how custom application to custom tabs assignment can be retrieved?

Can this be done through Apex code? SOQL?
Can this be done through SOAP API?
Can this be done through REST API?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through SOAP API method [describeTabs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describetabs.htm).

This method returns list of [describeTabSetResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describetabs_describetabsetresult.htm) which has tabs property which is list of [DescribeTab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describetabs_describetabsetresult_describetab.htm#topic-title) which has information about tab.